# Wrong matrix multiplication order in NSAffineTransform

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, matrix, quartz-2d

It seems to me that NSAffineTransform operations like `translateXBy:yBy:`, `rotateByDegrees:`, `scaleBy:`, and so on, use wrong order and prepend the required transformation matrix instead of appending it. So if you use the following:

```
NSAffineTransform* T = [NSAffineTransform new];
[T translateXBy: dx1 yBy: dy1]; // T1
[T rotateByDegrees: angle];     // T2
[T translateXBy: dx2 yBy: dy2]; // T3
```

, – it is the same as

```
NSAffineTransform* T  = [NSAffineTransform new];

NSAffineTransform* T1 = [NSAffineTransform new];
[T1 translateXBy: dx1 yBy: dy1]; // T1

NSAffineTransform* T2 = [NSAffineTransform new];
[T2 rotateByDegrees: angle];     // T2

NSAffineTransform* T3 = [NSAffineTransform new];
[T3 translateXBy: dx2 yBy: dy2]; // T3

[T prependTransform: T1];
[T prependTransform: T2];
[T prependTransform: T3];
```

According to Apple's [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-SW1) to produce a resultant point from a given one Quartz multiplies its coordinates represented as a row vector on a transformation matrix:

```
                        m11 m12 0
[x' y' 1] = [x y 1] * [ m21 m22 0 ]
                        tx  ty  1
```

So, in this case:

```
v'= v * T = v * T3 * T2 * T1
```

while the proper result should be:

```
v' = v * T1 * T2 * T3
```

The transformations are applied in a reverse order.

The old Apple's documentation had the following line in the **[`prependTransform:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAffineTransform_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAffineTransform/prependTransform%3a)**

> Concatenates aTransform's matrix with the receiver's matrix. Performs a multiplication of aTransform's matrix and the receiver's matrix, and replaces the receiver's matrix with the result. This has the effect of applying aTransform after the receiver's transform.

While the [new one](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSAffineTransform_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAffineTransform/prependTransform%3a) contains the following:

> This type of operation is the same as applying the transformations in aTransform followed by the transformations in the receiver.

The use of `prependTransform:` and its documentation would be correct, if Quartz used a left-multiplication transformation instead of a right-multiplicaation one it uses now.

Could anybody please comment on this ? Have I missed something or it is a known bug in an implementation?

Comment: Not directly an answer but as the docs state **You always start with an identity transform and add transformations to it** so **instead of** `[NSAffineTransform new];` start with the `[NSAffineTransform transform]` factory method which returns an object initialized to the identity matrix

Comment: Hmm, in my experience `+[NSAffineTransform new]` returns an identity transform. As far as I know it differs from `+[NSAffineTransform transform]` in that the second is autoreleased  (what is not important with ARC)?